# How to identify the Records (Order ID + Product ID combination) present in data1 but missing in data2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Data1** =

[image]

**Data2** =

[image]

The primary key for both data1 and data2 is Order Id + Product ID combination (i.e. the individual datasets do not have any duplicate on this combination)

Q1) How to identify the Records (Order ID + Product ID combination) present in data1 but missing in data2

Q2) How to identify the Records (Order ID + Product ID combination) missing in data1 but present in data2

```
df2["Record"] = df2["Order ID"]+df2["Product ID"]
df1["Record"] = df1["Order ID"]+df1["Product ID"]

df1.set_index("Record").subtract(df2.set_index("Record"), fill_value=0)
```

It gives me this error while trying to solve question 1

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Can you post text instead of images? That way. people can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `isin` or python `set`

> Q1) How to identify the Records (Order ID + Product ID combination) present in data1 but missing in data2

```py
m1 = ~df1["Record"].isin(df2["Record"])
res = df1.loc[m1, "Record"]
# or
res = set(df1["Record"]).difference(set(df2["Record"]))
```

> Q2) How to identify the Records (Order ID + Product ID combination) missing in data1 but present in data2

```py
m2 = ~df2["Record"].isin(df1["Record"])
res = df2.loc[m2, "Record"]
# or
res = set(df2["Record"]).difference(set(df1["Record"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

for Q1 you can do it like

```
[i for i in list(df1["Record"]) if i not in list(df2["Record"])]
```

and for Q2

```
[i for i in list(df2["Record"]) if i not in list(df1["Record"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try df.merge()

```
df_result = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on=['Order ID','Product ID'], how='left', indicator=True)
```

This will provide you with an indicator which tells you from where the record is from.

Then you can simply use `df_all['_merge'] == 'left_only'`.